# Regex replace replaces the whole word with the regex itself in VS code

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

Statement to be altered:

```
var test= $("find[id=match]");
```

I need to find all the entries in all the files in the folder which starts with `[` and ends with `]` and it should have two words separated by `=`
In this case: [id=match]
For this I used the following regex: `\[\w*\=\w*\]`

Now I want to change this to `[id='match']`

For this I used the following regex: `\[\w*\=\'\w*\'\]`

But the expected result is not happening.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to find all the occurences that matches your last regex like `[id='match']`? I tried your regex in https://regex101.com/r/GKoeqK/1 and it works.

Comment: @ALFA the problem is not with the finding regex. The issue is with replacing. Like  I need to replace the statement from **id=match** to id **id='match'** and this is not for a particular word. It should work for every word that comes. The concern is just to surround the word to the right of the **=** with quotation marks.

Comment: please provide sample data and expected output. thank you

Comment: @Simonare please find the following example: **[test= read]**. This should be changed to **[test='read']**

Comment: `(\[\w*=)(\w*)(])` -> `$1'$2'$3`

Comment: Can you please show how are you trying to replace the strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
(?<=\[\w*\=)(\w*)(?=\])
```

for matching regex. and for replace `'$1'`.

See [Regexr Demonstration](http://regexr.com/4a1kv)